# Navicat MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql

Estoy creando una `base de datos` y al momento de importar un archivo `SQL` con demasiados registros o simplemente que es muy pesado, me arroja el siguiente error:

> [Err] [Dtf] 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

Cabe mencionar que estoy utilizando [Navicat](https://www.navicat.com/es/whatsnew) para el manejo de la `Base de Datos`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solucion al error `2006` es aumentar los valores `max_allowed_packet` y `wait_timeout`.

1. Presionar `Tools > Server Monitor`.
2. Marcar la casilla del servidor que utiliza para la transferencia de datos.
3. Hacer clic en la pestaña `Variables`.
4. Encontrar las variables `max_allowed_packet` y `wait_timeout`.
5. Aumentar los valores de estas variables a un valor mas grande y presionar `OK`.

Con esto el problema queda totalmente solucionado debido a que se aumenta el  `tiempo de espera` y el `numero de paquetes máximo permitidos`.